# Is there a way to get a list of messages from a LIST of users in Slack?

Tags: slack

I am super tired of typing each user separately in the search box and do this every day.

Better to have a daily digest of these users send to my email box.

Answer (score 1):

Slack has no "follow" feature, where you can mark users you want to follow and then see all their message in a filtered view.

It would not be too hard to build a bot that does that though, so you might want to check the App Directory for a Slack app with this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The `All Unreads` view might be what you're looking for: it provides a digest of all unread direct messages as well as messages in channels that you haven't muted.

Enable `All Unreads` under your Preferences > Sidebar settings:

[image]

Then, click `All Unreads` in Slack's sidebar:

[image]

[Slack Help Reference](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/226410907-View-all-your-unread-messages)

Comment: well. it's not what I am looking for. I want to read only specific persons messages